ACF + Elementor Advanced Tabs - Using the same fields more than once in a post
I need to create a concert page with custom fields showing stuff like price, venue, url.
However, this concert will happen in multiple cities. My idea is for the Elementor Advanced Tabs to display these info but differently according to the city.
I can't seem to find a solution that allows the editor to fill in the same fields multiple times, each according to the city specifics (prices, venue and url are all different for each city).
